# SQL Server full-text index

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a table with full text index created on it.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo._mytable
(
    ID INT CONSTRAINT Pk_mytable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Name NVARCHAR(50)
)
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ft AS DEFAULT
GO  

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo._mytable(Name)   
   KEY INDEX Pk_mytable   
GO
```

The following query runs successfully

```
SELECT t.Name AS t_name
FROM dbo._mytable t
WHERE CONTAINS(t.Name, '"mu*"')
```

But this one fails

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT t.Name AS t_name
     FROM dbo._mytable t) T
WHERE CONTAINS(T.t_name, '"mu*"')
```

Error:

> Msg 7601, Level 16, State 3, Line 7
>   Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on column 't_name' because it is not full-text indexed

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: #Honeybadger Why it throws an error?

Answer (score 2):

The second one trows an error, because you are not selecting from the table with the full text index, but from a [derived table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#i-using-a-derived-table). The engine can't move the full text search from the outer select to the inner one.